# How to use a scala jar on Android?

Tags: java, android, scala

I created on Desktop (Intellij IDEA) a jar in java, kotlin and scala. I added these jars to the `lib` folder in the `android` project (Android Studio). The jars from java and kotlin worked. With the scala jar, the project compiled but the app crashed. I uses sbt in Intellij to build the scala jar.

My sourcecode:

```
package com.example.android1;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.kotlin.Custom;
import com.rip.Java;
import com.scala.Scala;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Java java = new Java(); java.hallo();
        Custom custom = new Custom(); custom.hallo();
        Scala scala = new Scala(); scala.scala();
    }
}
```

The `Java` class is from the Java jar, the `Custom` class frim the Kotlin jar and the `Scala` class from the Scala jar.

The errormessage from logcat (truncated):

```
2019-08-10 20:03:53.568 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: thread.cc:2097] Throwing new exception 'length=4; index=5' with unexpected pending exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4
2019-08-10 20:03:53.568 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: thread.cc:2097]   at void scala.collection.immutable.LazyList$.<clinit>() (LazyList.scala:938)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.568 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: thread.cc:2097]   at void scala.package$.<clinit>() (package.scala:89)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.568 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: thread.cc:2097]   at void scala.Predef$.<clinit>() (Predef.scala:154)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.568 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: thread.cc:2097]   at void com.scala.Scala.scala() (Scala.scala:4)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.568 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: thread.cc:2097]   at void com.example.android1.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:19)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.568 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: thread.cc:2097]   at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle, android.os.PersistableBundle) (Activity.java:7009)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.568 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: thread.cc:2097]   at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:7000)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.568 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: thread.cc:2097]   at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1214)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.568 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: thread.cc:2097]   at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2731)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.568 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: thread.cc:2097]   at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2856)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.568 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: thread.cc:2097]   at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.568 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: thread.cc:2097]   at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1589)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.568 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: thread.cc:2097]   at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:106)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.568 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: thread.cc:2097]   at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:164)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.568 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: thread.cc:2097]   at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6494)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.568 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: thread.cc:2097]   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.568 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: thread.cc:2097]   at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:438)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.568 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: thread.cc:2097]   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:807)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.568 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: thread.cc:2097] 
2019-08-10 20:03:53.602 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523] Runtime aborting...
2019-08-10 20:03:53.602 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523] Dumping all threads without appropriate locks held: thread list lock
2019-08-10 20:03:53.602 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523] All threads:
2019-08-10 20:03:53.602 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523] DALVIK THREADS (12):
2019-08-10 20:03:53.602 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523] "main" prio=10 tid=1 Runnable
2019-08-10 20:03:53.602 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x737e0978 self=0xec5d9000
2019-08-10 20:03:53.602 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   | sysTid=22281 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xf0f4c514
2019-08-10 20:03:53.602 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   | state=R schedstat=( 773061550 51995183 356 ) utm=66 stm=11 core=3 HZ=100
2019-08-10 20:03:53.602 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   | stack=0xff52a000-0xff52c000 stackSize=8MB
2019-08-10 20:03:53.602 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   | held mutexes= "abort lock" "mutator lock"(shared held)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.602 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #00 pc 0047eae1  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, int, BacktraceMap*, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*)+209)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.602 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #01 pc 0057c193  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::DumpStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+355)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.602 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #02 pc 00577693  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+83)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.602 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #03 pc 0059750e  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpCheckpoint::Run(art::Thread*)+1118)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.602 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #04 pc 0058e9f6  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ThreadList::RunCheckpoint(art::Closure*, art::Closure*)+534)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.602 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #05 pc 0058dfec  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ThreadList::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, bool)+284)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.602 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #06 pc 0055f1b1  /system/lib/libart.so (art::AbortState::DumpAllThreads(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, art::Thread*) const+289)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.602 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #07 pc 0055edd0  /system/lib/libart.so (art::AbortState::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&) const+176)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.602 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #08 pc 0054d366  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+198)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.602 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #09 pc 0011fb23  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIPFvPKcENS_9allocatorIS5_EES4_EclEOS3_+35)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.602 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #10 pc 0065f2eb  /system/lib/libart.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+1051)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.602 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #11 pc 00582210  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::AssertNoPendingExceptionForNewException(char const*) const+1248)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.602 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #12 pc 00585f07  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::ThrowNewException(char const*, char const*)+39)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.602 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #13 pc 001b6094  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ThrowException(char const*, art::ObjPtr<art::mirror::Class>, char const*, char**)+644)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.602 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #14 pc 001b626f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ThrowArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(int, int)+96)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.602 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #15 pc 00455cb7  /system/lib/libart.so (art::mirror::Array::ThrowArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(int)+39)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.602 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #16 pc 00198d21  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ClassLinker::ResolveMethodHandleForMethod(art::Thread*, art::DexFile const*, art::DexFile::MethodHandleItem const&, art::ArtMethod*)+2913)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.602 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #17 pc 0019940d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ClassLinker::ResolveMethodHandle(unsigned int, art::ArtMethod*)+141)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.602 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #18 pc 0031cc5f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::InvokeBootstrapMethod(art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, unsigned int)+623)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.602 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #19 pc 0031c698  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter14DoInvokeCustomILb0EEEbPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+408)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.603 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #20 pc 0032d259  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter17ExecuteSwitchImplILb1ELb0EEENS_6JValueEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameES2_b+40697)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.603 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #21 pc 002f3c2a  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool)+1050)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.603 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #22 pc 002fa1cb  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame*)+139)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.603 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #23 pc 006179bf  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1311)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.603 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #24 pc 0064832d  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+77)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.603 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #25 pc 00642432  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+418)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.603 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #26 pc 001160f9  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+265)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.603 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #27 pc 00184706  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ClassLinker::InitializeClass(art::Thread*, art::Handle<art::mirror::Class>, bool, bool)+3366)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.603 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #28 pc 00168207  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ClassLinker::EnsureInitialized(art::Thread*, art::Handle<art::mirror::Class>, bool, bool)+247)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.603 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #29 pc 0062e609  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpGetObjStatic+345)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.603 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #30 pc 00632c9d  /system/lib/libart.so (artMterpAsmInstructionStart+12573)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.603 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #31 pc 002f3a2b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool)+539)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.603 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #32 pc 002fa1cb  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame*)+139)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.603 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #33 pc 006179bf  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1311)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.603 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #34 pc 0064832d  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+77)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.603 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #35 pc 00642432  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+418)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.603 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #36 pc 001160f9  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+265)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.604 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #37 pc 00184706  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ClassLinker::InitializeClass(art::Thread*, art::Handle<art::mirror::Class>, bool, bool)+3366)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.604 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #38 pc 00168207  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ClassLinker::EnsureInitialized(art::Thread*, art::Handle<art::mirror::Class>, bool, bool)+247)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.604 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #39 pc 0062e609  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpGetObjStatic+345)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.604 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #40 pc 00632c9d  /system/lib/libart.so (artMterpAsmInstructionStart+12573)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.604 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #41 pc 002f3a2b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool)+539)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.604 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #42 pc 002fa1cb  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame*)+139)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.604 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #43 pc 006179bf  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1311)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.604 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #44 pc 0064832d  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+77)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.604 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #45 pc 00642432  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+418)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.604 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #46 pc 001160f9  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+265)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.604 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #47 pc 00184706  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ClassLinker::InitializeClass(art::Thread*, art::Handle<art::mirror::Class>, bool, bool)+3366)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.604 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #48 pc 00168207  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ClassLinker::EnsureInitialized(art::Thread*, art::Handle<art::mirror::Class>, bool, bool)+247)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.604 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #49 pc 0062e609  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpGetObjStatic+345)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.604 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #50 pc 00632c9d  /system/lib/libart.so (artMterpAsmInstructionStart+12573)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.604 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #51 pc 002f3a2b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool)+539)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.604 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #52 pc 002fa2e7  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+231)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.604 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #53 pc 0031a78a  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+810)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.604 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #54 pc 00627e14  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+756)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.604 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #55 pc 006332a1  /system/lib/libart.so (artMterpAsmInstructionStart+14113)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.604 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #56 pc 002f3a2b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool)+539)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.604 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #57 pc 002fa2e7  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+231)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.604 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #58 pc 0031a78a  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+810)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.604 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #59 pc 00627e14  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+756)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.604 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #60 pc 006332a1  /system/lib/libart.so (artMterpAsmInstructionStart+14113)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.604 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #61 pc 002f3a2b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool)+539)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.604 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #62 pc 002fa2e7  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+231)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.604 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   native: #63 pc 0031a78a  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+810)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.604 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   at scala.collection.immutable.LazyList$.<clinit>(LazyList.scala:938)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.604 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   at scala.package$.<clinit>(package.scala:89)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.604 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   at scala.Predef$.<clinit>(Predef.scala:154)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.604 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   at com.scala.Scala.scala(Scala.scala:4)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.604 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   at com.example.android1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.604 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.604 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.604 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.604 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.605 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.605 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java:-1)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.605 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.605 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.605 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.605 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.605 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native method)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.605 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.605 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.605 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523] 
2019-08-10 20:03:53.605 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523] "Jit thread pool worker thread 0" prio=10 tid=2 Native
2019-08-10 20:03:53.605 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x13d00000 self=0xe4908000
2019-08-10 20:03:53.605 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   | sysTid=22286 nice=9 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xe48ff970
2019-08-10 20:03:53.605 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   | state=S schedstat=( 16778172 2527777 47 ) utm=1 stm=0 core=2 HZ=100
2019-08-10 20:03:53.605 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   | stack=0xe4801000-0xe4803000 stackSize=1022KB
2019-08-10 20:03:53.605 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   | held mutexes=
2019-08-10 20:03:53.605 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:523]   kernel: futex_wait_queue_me+0xdf/0x130
......

2019-08-10 20:03:53.616 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 22281 (xample.android1), pid 22281 (xample.android1)
2019-08-10 20:03:53.616 22281-22281/com.example.android1 A/zygote: runtime.cc:531]
```

Comment: Please add the stack trace, error messages and so on that would allow someone to diagnose the problem.   (There are any number of reasons that an app can crash.)

Comment: The logcat is very long. Idon't know, wich part I should copy.

Comment: Is it possible in general, to execute a scala jar on android?

Comment: Well, yes.  If you do it correctly.  See https://scala-android.org/